# Extracting specific cells from multiple Excel files and compile it into one Excel file

Tags: vba, excel, loops, syntax-error

I'm new to VBA, and I'd like to use it to do some difficult and arduous tasks. I have a large amount of Excel files with thousands of rows and several columns. I need to search, by row, and extract certain cells with specific strings. I've pieced together some functions and code and I have almost got it to work but I keep getting unexpected results like irrelevant data being extracted or it random errors because I don't understand VBA syntax super well. As a newbie to Excel, I'm at my wits end debugging this code and it still not giving me the results I need. My code thus far is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportDataFromMultipleFiles()
Dim firstAddress As Variant
Dim filenames As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rFind As Range
Dim firstFile As String
Dim n As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim myArray() As Integer

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("a2").Select
filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(FileFilter:="Excel Filter(*xlsx), *.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True)
Application.FindFormat.Clear

For i = 1 To UBound(filenames) 'counter for files
firstFile = filenames(i)
Workbooks.Open firstFile 'Opens individual files in folder
n = 0

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      Set rFind = .Find("Test*Results:", Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rFind.Address
            Do
            n = n + 1
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            Selection.Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Selection.PasteSpecial
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            Loop While Not rFind Is Nothing And rFind.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

ReDim myArray(0, n)
n = 0
Workbooks.Open firstFile 'Opens individual files in folder

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set rFind = .Find("Test*Results:", Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rFind.Address
            Do
            myArray(0, n) = rFind.Row '<<< Error currently here
            n = n + 1
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            Selection.Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Selection.PasteSpecial
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            Loop While Not rFind Is Nothing And rFind.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

For n = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
Debug.Print "Rows are: " & myArray(0, n)
Next n

Workbooks.Open filenames(i)
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Next i

End Sub
```

I'm not even sure if the second loop is necessary, but using it has given me the closest results for what I'm looking for thus far. This code is going to cover a lot of data, so any suggestions to make my code more efficient as well will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need all that code.

Try this out - it's easier to manage if you split out the "find" part into a separate method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportDataFromMultipleFiles()

    Dim filenames As Variant, wb As Workbook
    Dim rngDest As Range, colFound As Collection, f, i As Long

    Set rngDest = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") '<< results start here

    filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel Filter(*xlsx), *.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True)

    If TypeName(filenames) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub '<< nothing selected

    Application.FindFormat.Clear

    For i = 1 To UBound(filenames) 'counter for files

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filenames(i))
        Set colFound = FindAll(wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange, "Test*Results:") '<< get matches
        Debug.Print "Found " & colFound.Count & " matches in " & wb.Name '<<EDIT
        For Each f In colFound
            f.Copy rngDest
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
            Debug.Print "", f.Value
        Next f

        wb.Close False
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Okay, much more efficient! I like your FindAll function, it helps simplify things. I am not familiar with a public function though, will it run correctly if I just put it in with the rest of the VBA code or is there something special I need to do with it?

Comment: You should be able to just add it to your module.  In this case it likely doesn't need to be `Public`, so you could remove that keyword.

Comment: Alright, I put it in my module and I'm not getting any data in my main Excel spread sheet. It's allowing me to select the files like before and the code runs but my spread sheet remains blank. That's not much to go off of, but any suggestions?

Comment: Is there only a single sheet in each workbook being opened? Do you see any output in the Immediate pane in the VB editor?

Comment: My string I was using to find cells wasn't working, your code works beautifully. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have been able to understand and manipulate this code for my data, except for one part. In the public function, FindAll, when you set up f, you use the after function as on of the optional variants. The way you used it is very fancy and efficient and I don't understand it. Do you mind clarifying how that part works? Or, even better, can you help me use it if I'm referring to a specific range, also attained by using the find function, that I find in my data before I even begin my search for f?

Comment: It's pretty well expalined here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel   Also, I think I adapted that code from elsewhere, so probably not even my work...

Comment: That wasn't quite me question, but I figured it out! My code is now complete. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I mis-understood your question.  If you were asking about `rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count)` it's basically "start looking after the  last cell in the range", which means start looking in the *first* cell of the range, since Find always loops around when it get to the end of the range to be searched.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks!