# Why findnext method is not working in my excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

Findnext method is not working in the procedure "Sub Loadschedule()"
First find method found a range that I intended then findnext method found nothing "Set teacherfind = teachername.FindNext(teacherfind)" eventhough there are still same in the range "teachername"

However, if I removed the procedure "color_available_Sch" contained in the "Sub Loadschedule()", it would work.

```
Sub Loadschedule()
Dim WS_sch As Worksheet 'Sheet schedule display
Dim WS_T As Worksheet 'Sheet Teacher list
Dim WS_S As Worksheet 'Sheet Student list
Dim Av_Day(1 To 7) As Integer 'Available day, mon to sun
Dim Av_time_hrs_STRT As Integer
Dim Av_time_hrs_END As Integer
Dim Av_time_min_STRT As Integer
Dim Av_time_min_END As Integer
Dim teacher_select As String 'teacher selected in schedule display
Dim teachername As Range 'column teacher name in the teacher list
Dim teacherfind As Range 'cell corresponding to the selected teacher name
Dim i As Integer 'for loop
Dim firstaddress
Dim checkaddress
Set WS_sch = Sheets("Schedule")
Set WS_T = Sheets("Teacher")
Set WS_S = Sheets("Student")

teacher_select = WS_sch.Range("Teacher_Selected")
Set teachername = WS_T.Range("B:B")
Set teacherfind = teachername.Find(teacher_select, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not teacherfind Is Nothing Then
firstaddress = teacherfind.address
Do


Av_time_hrs_STRT = teacherfind.Offset(0, 2)
Av_time_min_STRT = teacherfind.Offset(0, 3)
Av_time_hrs_END = teacherfind.Offset(0, 4)
Av_time_min_END = teacherfind.Offset(0, 5)
For i = 1 To 7
    If teacherfind.Offset(0, i + 5) = "" Then
    Av_Day(i) = 0
    Else
    Av_Day(i) = 1
    End If
Next i

color_available_Sch Av_Day, Av_time_hrs_STRT, Av_time_hrs_END, Av_time_min_STRT, Av_time_min_END, WS_sch

checkaddress = teachername.address


Set teacherfind = teachername.FindNext(teacherfind)
checkaddress = teacherfind.address
Loop While Not teacherfind Is Nothing And teacherfind.address <> firstaddress
End If


End Sub
Sub color_available_Sch(ByRef Av_Day() As Integer, ByVal Av_time_hrs_STRT As Integer, _
ByVal Av_time_hrs_END As Integer, ByVal Av_time_min_STRT As Integer, ByVal Av_time_min_END As Integer, ByVal WS_sch As Worksheet)
Dim day_sch As Range
Dim day_find As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstaddress
Dim rng_color_STRT As Range
Dim rng_color_END As Range

Set day_sch = WS_sch.Range("S:S")
For i = 1 To 7
If Av_Day(i) = 1 Then
Set day_find = day_sch.Find((i + 1 Mod 7), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not day_find Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = day_find.address
    Do
        If Av_time_hrs_STRT <= 15 Then
        Set rng_color_STRT = day_find.Offset(0, 2 * (Av_time_hrs_STRT + Av_time_min_STRT / 60) - 32)
        Set rng_color_END = rng_color_STRT.Offset( _
        0, 2 * (Av_time_hrs_END + Av_time_min_END / 60 - Av_time_hrs_STRT + Av_time_min_STRT / 60))

        ElseIf Av_time_hrs_STRT > 15 Then
        Set rng_color_STRT = day_find.Offset(1, 2 * (Av_time_hrs_STRT + Av_time_min_STRT / 60) - 32)
        Set rng_color_END = rng_color_STRT.Offset( _
        1, 2 * (Av_time_hrs_END + Av_time_min_END / 60 - Av_time_hrs_STRT + Av_time_min_STRT / 60))
        End If


    With Range(rng_color_STRT, rng_color_END).Interior


        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With
    Set day_find = day_sch.FindNext(day_find)
    checkaddress = day_find.address
    Loop While Not day_find Is Nothing And day_find.address <> firstaddress
    End If
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

In the range "teacherName", there are a few same name. I used findnext method so that I can do same thing (shown the sub procedure color_available_Sch) for all same name.

However, it didn't work in Sub loadschedule procedure with its sub procedure.

Comment: FindNext doesn't work in custom functions so it may not also work in subs with arguments. No doubt someone can confirm. In any case you can use Find, specifying the After parameter, in place of FindNext.

Comment: You're running a separate Find from within your loop: Excel will not "remember" the search that was in place when you called that sub.  You'll need a different approach to that - consider making a separate "Findall" function which returns (eg) a Collection of matches which you can then safely loop over in a nested fashion.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651346/extracting-specific-cells-from-multiple-excel-files-and-compile-it-into-one-exce/50651559#50651559

Comment: Tim Williams, Thank you. I'll try to find another way with your refence findall function.