# Not able to get around object not set error with exceptions

Tags: excel, vba, search, null

I am at an impasse figuring out how to catch this null range variable exception.

I am attempting to scan for a row of headers to recover data from a few rows under, the excel datasheets may have multiple "pages"  with a new header and date on the next "page" if there happens to be data to fill it and this can extend to many pages.

My loop appears to break on the second pass after the find function is unable to find additional rows with the desired header. My if statement is not able to detect that the variable is blank and I get an object not set error repeatedly.

I have tried several ways at calling null exceptions such as is empty, is null, both in a few different syntax forms, but still no success.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub testingBreak()
Dim testing As String
Dim starting As String
testing = "testing"
starting = "starting"
Dim productNameRange() As Range
Dim PN2CellAddress As String
Dim rowCount As Integer
rowCount = 0
Dim oldCount As Integer
oldCount = 0
ReDim productNameRange(rowCount)
Dim r As Integer

Set productNameRange(rowCount) = Sheets(starting).Cells.Find( _
    What:="Product Name", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

If productNameRange(rowCount) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Search Error: Header Not found")
Else
    Do While Not IsEmpty(productNameRange(rowCount))   'this is to search for additional rows with the same header name
       oldCount = rowCount
       rowCount = rowCount + 1
       MsgBox rowCount & " & " & oldCount
 
      ReDim Preserve productNameRange(rowCount)
      If IsNull(productNameRange(oldCount)) Then '<<<<this if statement does not catch that the variable was not set :(      <<<<<
          MsgBox "null exception worked"
      Else
          MsgBox productNameRange(oldCount) '<<<<on second loop, I get the error "object variable or with block variable not set"...               <<<<<<
      End If
      Set productNameRange(rowCount) = Sheets(starting).Range(productNameRange(oldCount).Address).FindNext( _
           productNameRange(oldCount)) ' <<<  does not set the next range if there is none
     Loop
     MsgBox rowCount & "Row(s) have been found!"
     For r = 0 To rowCount - 1
         MsgBox productNameRange(r)
     Next r
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to know if a range variable is set to something or not, you should use `Is Nothing` as you do initially, not `IsEmpty()` or `IsNull()`  The other thing to keep in mind if that once you've found one match, `Find()` will just keep returning a hit, since it always loops back to the beginning after finding the last match in a range.  So you need to account for that also.  It's easier to split your "find all matches" logic out into a separate so it doesn't clutter up your main code: eg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651559/478884

Comment: Fair enough, I will look into that. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @TimWilliams I am runing into the same error with this line in the function you suggested ```  If f.Address = addr Then ```

Comment: object varriable or with block varriable not set is the error

Comment: @TimWilliams I am able to comment out that line and the search works fine if there is just one value to find, if there are many it loops forever

Comment: `If f.Address = addr Then` would fail  with that message when `f` is nothing, but that should never be the case if the code entered the `Do Until f Is Nothing` loop.  Unless you're replacing the cell value within the loop, which is not what the code I posted is designed around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seemed to fix my issue. Thank you to everyone for your help

```
Dim f As Variant


Private Function FindAllHeaderRows(val As String, filePath As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, g As Range
    Dim addr As String
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath) ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set g = ws.Cells.Find(What:=val, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not g Is Nothing Then addr = g.Address

    Do Until g Is Nothing
        rv.Add g
        Set g = ws.Cells.FindNext(After:=g)
       If Not g Is Nothing Then
       If g.Address = addr Then Exit Do
       End If
    Loop

    Set FindAllHeaderRows = rv
End Function                                 'working!


Sub testSub1()
Dim FileToOpen As String
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Data file")
   Set rangeCo = FindAllHeaderRows("Product Name", FileToOpen)
For Each f In rangeCo
MsgBox f.Address 'shows address
Next f
MsgBox rangeCo.count  ' shows how many
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Find Criteria Cells (`Find` & `FindNext`)

```vb
Sub FindCriteriaCells()

    Const wsName As String = "Starting"
    Const Criteria As String = "Product Name"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = rg.Find(What:=Criteria, _
        After:=rg.Cells(rg.Rows.Count, rg.Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True)
    
    Dim Headers() As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim FirstAddress As String: FirstAddress = fCell.Address
        Do
            ReDim Preserve Headers(0 To n)
            Set Headers(n) = fCell
            n = n + 1
            Set fCell = rg.FindNext(After:=fCell)
        Loop Until fCell.Address = FirstAddress
    End If
    
    Dim Msg As String
    
    If n > 0 Then
        Msg = "The header '" & Criteria & "' was found in " _
            & n & " cell(s):" & vbLf
        For n = 0 To n - 1
            Msg = Msg & vbLf & Headers(n).Address(0, 0)
        Next n
        MsgBox Msg, vbInformation
    Else
        Msg = "The header '" & Criteria & "' was not found."
        MsgBox Msg, vbExclamation
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

This however seems to cause the same error when run on its own:  Object variable or with block variable not set

the error is thrown at this line of code :  Loop Until fCell.Address = FirstAddress

Comment: Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Feel free to download [my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19SL3yBp5KCMteyP4K2mITLvklkrq8N06/view?usp=sharing) from Google Drive. The Find method is unreliable when the worksheet is **filtered**. To avoid this, after referencing the worksheet (`Set ws = ...`), you could use the line `If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAlldata` to remove any filters. Additionally, if you use the `xlValues` parameter of the `LookIn` argument, hidden cells (due to hiding rows or columns) containing the criteria will also not be found. If you could share your workbook, I would be able to take a closer look.