# Find string value in the same row as a given range address

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I have a search that Identifies a range address with a specific header that works.

The function I am working on needs to search in the same row for another header string and return the cell address.

For some reason the find function does not populate the range variable with the  address of the header in the file.

I have tried adjusting parameters in the find function but I am not having any luck figuring this out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```vb
Private Sub FindAllHeadersInRow(dataFile As String, rng As String, headerName As String)
MsgBox "Finding all headers in the selected row"
'search left in the given row to find other header to copy data from under
Dim HeaderColFoundRng As Range
Dim dataWB As Workbook
Set dataWB = Workbooks.Open(dataFile)
Set HeaderColFoundRng = dataWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(rng).Find(What:=headerName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 'or xlNext
    'needs to set each value address to a range that will be sent out
    
    MsgBox HeaderColFoundRng.Address  '<<< repeated variable not set error!
        
End Sub

Sub testSub2()
Dim FileToOpen As String
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Data file")
Call FindAllHeadersInRow(FileToOpen, "A68:AZ68", "Transaction Date") 'Header needed is located in T68
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.Find()` will return `Nothing` if no match is found for your `headerName`. This seems to me the most obvious reason for the error you mentioned: `HeaderColFoundRng = Nothing`, so that `HeaderColFoundRng.Address` does not exist. You can error handle this: `If Not HeaderColFoundRng Is Nothing Then` \ your MsgBox \ `else` \ do something \ `End If`

Comment: I can use my initial function to search for this string and verify that it is in fact in cell "$T$68" (as well as 2 other locations on different rows that I don't need).  

why would searching the row left from the cell AZ68 not find the match if "Transaction Date" if it is fact verified to be in that row at T68?

Comment: There's no way for us to troubleshoot this without access to the file in question.  I've never experienced `Find()` failing to make a match when the value being searched for is present (as long as you supply the appropriate arguments).  There is a slight issue locating content in hidden cells, where you need to use `xlFormulas` instead of `xlValues` for `LookIn`, but otherwise it has always worked for me.  FYI if you only need to make an exact match in a single column/row then using `Application.Match()` can be faster.

Comment: Could also help to share your initial function, so that we may compare the two and see why they yield different results. One other thing I can imagine, is that cell `T68` contains something like "Transaction Date ", i.e. including a trailing space. If so, you won't find a match, because of `LookAt:=xlWhole`, and could try using `LookAt:=xlPart` instead.

Comment: Here is the initial function that is able to find the value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72410850/not-able-to-get-around-object-not-set-error-with-exceptions?noredirect=1#comment127965157_72410850

Comment: I also checked last night to see if there was some additional character like a space, which in this instance is not the case. I am also unable to share the data file at this time due to a work policy. I greatly appreciate everyone's efforts helping solve this, as it stands I am currently attempting a workaround that just does a full scan of the page for each of the other headers that I need to scan data from under (instead of just scanning left and right in the known row for the other needed headers like this would eventually do)