# How to iterate through all instances in which a name appears

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code.

```
Sub copy2Sheets()
Const N As Long = 116 'use const for fixed values

Dim wsTable As Worksheet, wsBBS As Worksheet, i As Long
Dim wsDest As Worksheet, f As Range, tempDep As String, tempName As String

Set wsTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
Set wsBBS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Last Month's BBS SafeUnsafe by ")

For i = 1 To N
    tempDep = Trim(wsTable.Cells(i, "B").Value)
    tempName = Trim(wsTable.Cells(i, "A").Value)
    If Len(tempName) > 0 Then
        Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tempDep)
        Set f = wsBBS.Columns("C").Find(what:=tempName, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
             f.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Essentially, this code pulls value from a sheet with a pair (name, department) and then checks a report generated by an office. If the name is present in the report, it will then use the department to add that name's report onto another sheet based on department.

The code works well, however there are instances in which a person will make a report more than once, which is to be expected. How can I go about ensuring that all instances of which the name appear are properly copied? As it stands right now, we are only copying the first instance.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: See `FindAll` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651559/478884  for an example of how to use Find in a loop.  Your title mentions merged cells though?

Comment: Most of the time, avoiding merged cells is best practice. It's not really clear what the issue is though - your title and post don't seem to be getting at same problem. Provide more details and specific issues you are having with examples (actual vs expected outcome - error you are getting, etc.)

Comment: Hi, I updated the question - I am so sorry for the confusion!